# Converting standard time to military time widget

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a widget that will create a military time string from a series of dropdowns. I'm using it to create an interface for users of a website that need to put in events using standard time but the calendar widget needs military time.

I've got a start but can't seem to figure it out. The code is on jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jwp64/

Might be easier to see it there. I've got the function there, just can't seem to get it to apply to text field.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please clarify. Military time can mean a number of things. I am an Army Officer and you also have to consider time zones such as Zulu, Romeo, Charlie, etc. So do you want 24 hr clock or a true military time?

Comment: I need 24 hour time. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/Jwp64/6/

Here is a more verbose form of what is in the fiddle:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
    var ampm = $("#open-times-ampm").val();
    var hour = $("#open-times-hour").val();
    var minute = $("#open-times-minute").val();
    var milTime = convertToMilitaryTime(ampm,hour,minute);

    $('#open-time').val( milTime );

    return false;
});
```

Also, when using jsFiddle, you don't need `<script>` tags in the Javascript section, and select jQuery in the dropdown on the left.

Comment: Thanks for the help! First time using jsFiddle so I'm still learning. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle, there were some things that were not right: try it here http://jsfiddle.net/Jwp64/7/